# Using Ehcache to cache objects into JVM's memory and into Disk

Tags: ehcache

I want to use the cache to manage 500mb data ,so I made a test.  I want to put 200mb data into JVM's memory and other 300mb put into disk.

So every element I had put 2mb data, I had set the CacheManager's MaxBytesLocalHeap 250mb and Cache's MaxBytesLocalHeap 200mb, but when I finished my case, I found that there are more 170mb data in JVM and the disk data was more than 290mb. I printed the keys in disk, I found there are 250 keys, not 150 keys.

It means that: the disk data has 250 keys and there are 500mb data in disk data , it's not my wanted ...

I don't know why ? I watched the codes, but I hadn't find the reasons , this is my test code :

```
private static final String CACHE_PATH = "java.io.tmpdir";
private static String MAX_MEMORY = "512m";
private static String BLOCK_MAX_MEMORY = "512m";
private static String DATA_MAX_MEMORY = "512m";

private static MCacheManager instance;
private Properties props = null;
private CacheManager cacheManager = null;
private Cache memoryCache;
private Cache dataCache;

public static MCacheManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (MCacheManager.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MCacheManager();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

private MCacheManager() {
    super();
    double maxMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() *0.4) / (1024*1024);//m
    MAX_MEMORY = maxMemory+"";
}

public Cache memoryCache() {
    if (memoryCache == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (memoryCache == null) {
                String maxMemory = getProperty("block.cache.max.memory", BLOCK_MAX_MEMORY);
                memoryCache = getCache("__memoryCache__",maxMemory,false);
            }
        }
    }
    return memoryCache;
}

public Cache dataCache() {
    if (dataCache == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            String maxMemory = getProperty("data.cache.max.memory", DATA_MAX_MEMORY);
            dataCache = getCache("__dataCache__",maxMemory,true);
        }
    }
    return dataCache;
}

private Cache getCache(String cacheName, String maxMemory, boolean saveDisk) {
    Cache cache = getCacheManager().getCache(cacheName);
    if (cache == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            cache = getCacheManager().getCache(cacheName);
            if (cache == null) {
                CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration();
                cacheConfig.name(cacheName);
                cacheConfig.eternal(false);
                cacheConfig.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
                cacheConfig.setOverflowToDisk(saveDisk);
                cacheConfig.setDiskPersistent(true);
                cacheConfig.setMaxBytesLocalHeap(maxMemory);
                cache = new Cache(cacheConfig);
                getCacheManager().addCache(cache);
            }
        }
    }
    return cache;
}

private CacheManager getCacheManager() {
    if (cacheManager == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (cacheManager == null) {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                DiskStoreConfiguration dscg = new DiskStoreConfiguration();
                dscg.setPath(getProperty("cache.path.disk", CACHE_PATH));
                configuration.diskStore(dscg);
                configuration.setMaxBytesLocalHeap(getProperty("cache.manager.max.memory", MAX_MEMORY));
                configuration.setDynamicConfig(true);
                configuration.setMonitoring("autodetect");
                configuration.setUpdateCheck(false);
                cacheManager = new CacheManager(configuration);
            }
        }
    }
    return cacheManager;
}

private String getProperty(String key, String defaultValue) {
    if (props == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (props == null) {
                try {
                    InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/cache.properties");
                    if (stream == null) {
                        stream = MCacheManager.class.getResourceAsStream("/cache.properties");
                    }
                    props = new Properties();
                    props.load(stream);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return props.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
}
```

this is the cache.properties :

> ####################### Your Cache Settings
>   
>   ######## cache file path ##############                                                                                                                                                                                               = 100m cache.path.disk = f:\
>   
>   ######## cacheManager max memorySize k|K|m|M|g|G##############                                                                                                                                                                                               = 100m cache.manager.max.memory = 1000m
>   
>   ######## BlockSet Cache
>   
>   ######## max memory , k|K|m|M|g|G ##############                                                                                                                                                                                               = 100m block.cache.max.memory = 100m
>   
>   ######## DataSet Cache
>   
>   ######## max memory , k|K|m|M|g|G##############                                                                                                                                                                                               = 100m data.cache.max.memory = 100m

I want to some hope : for 300mb data . 
how to use cache to manage 200mb data in JVM and 300mb data into disk ...

Comment: sorry , i want to use  ehcache to manage 500mb datas ,not 300mb datas.